# Trigger Blur Event on clicking on the Input not clicking outside

Tags: jquery, events, focus, blur

I have an input box where when i click on it it gets focused and when i click somewhere outside it gets blurred ( blur event is triggered ) - This is normal functionality.

But What i want is to blur the input box on clicking it again unlike clicking outside. Something of toggle blur and focus.

PS : Actually i am using a datepicker on the above mentioned input box. I want to open the datepicker on clicking the input and close the datepicker on clicking on it again.

Comment: Which datepicker plugin you are using ?

Comment: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var clickcnt=1;
$("input").click((function(){
    if(clickcnt) {
        //single click action
        clickcnt=0;
    } else {
        //double click action
        $(this).blur();// trigger blur event of this input box
        clickcnt=1
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. hope help you...

http://jsfiddle.net/wwH7n/

**jquery**

```
  var clickCount = 0;
  $('#txt').click(function () {
      clickCount = (clickCount == 2) ? 0 : clickCount;
      if (clickCount == 0) {
          alert("first click do something");
      } else if (clickCount == 1) {
          alert("second click do different");
      }
      clickCount++;
  });
```